# php form tags not working? (undefined variable error)

Tags: php, html

First of all, I am using wamp server and learning basic PHP grammar.

so my first form php file is

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
Name:  <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
```

and the foo.php file is

```
<?php 
// Available since PHP 4.1.0

echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_REQUEST['username'];

import_request_variables('p', 'p_');
echo $p_username;

// As of PHP 5.0.0, these long predefined variables can be
// disabled with the register_long_arrays directive.

echo $HTTP_POST_VARS['username'];

// Available if the PHP directive register_globals = on. As of 
// PHP 4.2.0 the default value of register_globals = off.
// Using/relying on this method is not preferred.

echo $username;
?>
```

but when I open localhost/form2.php    it works fine and then I input "username" and "email". After that it gives the following error:

Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_POST_VARS in C:\wamp\www\foo.php on line 13
 Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\wamp\www\foo.php on line 19

Apparently, these codes are supposed to work,, but it's not working for me for some reason. Is there something wrong with wamp server? or possibly something wrong with how I set up the configuration?? Thank you !

Comment: er... line 19 is throwing an error because $username is undefined...

Comment: $HTTP_POST_VARS is deprecated; see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: What php version are you using ? <?php echo phpinfo() ?>

Comment: Basically, the correct answer is included in the comments inside your `foo.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php), `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated. Actually they are not available anymore since PHP5.4, so no wonder it says `Undefined variable`.

`$username`, this only works with `REGISTER_GLOBALS=ON` - your WAMP probably has this on `OFF`, as it should be.

Summa summarum: Use `$_POST`

Comment: It still existed in PHP *5*. PHP 5.4 apparently removed it! http://3v4l.org/XEjF4

Answer (score 2):

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is undefined because [`register_long_arrays`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays) has been turned off. If you're using PHP 5.4.0 then it has been *removed*.

Answer (score 0):

The function import_request_variables() has been deprecated and removed as of php version 5.4.0.

Use $_POST instead of $HTTP_POST_VARS. The latter is deprecated also.

Do something like this instead:

```
<?php
$userName = '';
$email = '';

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $userName = $_POST['username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}


echo 'username=' . $userName;
echo 'email=' . $email;
?>
```